# How can I curl -IL all the website pages starting with the root pagenot just 1 page at the time?

Tags: nginx, cache, fastcgi, curl

I need to curl -IL all the website and maybe do cron job or something every 24hrs so fastcgi can cache all the pages on [vgo](https://www.vgopromo.com)

The cache don't hit unless I curl -IL the webpage so I need something that will curl all the webpage available on the website.

Like you can see bellow:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-amd-sfo3-01:~# curl -IL https://www.example.com
HTTP/2 200 
date: Thu, 23 Feb 2023 10:31:44 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
link: <https://www.example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
link: <https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/16274>; rel="alternate"; type="application/json"
link: <https://www.example.com/>; rel=shortlink
x-fastcgi-cache: HIT
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=2K%2BxMLMMrvGpe%2FdpG38gU%2FKaBPBAL5I3rYNL5ATQ65wPM2qMnQmaCe2jLx88N%2B%2BHeUw1RRI5EnrYh9%2F6P5fj7xAipg%2FnOxi4IV8e4IqPWMyANW9JnKndXGfBZw0r3LtF1IEl"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 79df4b241af32f15-LAX
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's WordPress what you using there. I'm sure there are better ways to warm up the cache: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/search/cache+warm/

**Create a file like warmup.sh with the following code**

```
#!/bin/bash

# URL of main Sitemap
sitemap_url="https://www.vgopromo.com/wp-sitemap.xml"

# Extract all Sitemap URLs
sitemap_urls=$(curl -s "$sitemap_url" | grep -oP '(?<=<loc>)[^<]+')

# Loop over and retrieve the individual URLs
for sitemap in $sitemap_urls; do
    urls=$(curl -s "$sitemap" | grep -oP '(?<=<loc>)[^<]+')
    for url in $urls; do
        curl -IL "$url"
    done
done
```

This will do what you requested.

You can also a Cronjob that run this file.

```
# Example: At minute 15 past every hour.
15 */1 * * * /bin/bash /root/warmup.sh
```

**EDIT**

This modified code adds the option to define also subdomains.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Array of Subdomains, just extend in same princip
subdomains=("www" "subdomain_2")

# Loop over Subdomains and retrieve URLs
for subdomain in "${subdomains[@]}"; do
    sitemap_url="https://$subdomain.vgopromo.com/wp-sitemap.xml"
    sitemap_urls=$(curl -s "$sitemap_url" | grep -oP '(?<=<loc>)[^<]+')
    for sitemap in $sitemap_urls; do
        urls=$(curl -s "$sitemap" | grep -oP '(?<=<loc>)[^<]+')
        for url in $urls; do
            curl -IL "$url"
        done
    done
done
```

Ill personally suggest this way. Makes it compatible with multiple projects

```
#!/bin/bash

# Array of Domains, just extend in same princip
domains=("https://www.vgopromo.com/wp-sitemap.xml" "https://example.vgopromo.com/wp-sitemap.xml")

# Loop over Domains and retrieve URLs
for domain in "${domains[@]}"; do
    sitemap_url="$domain"
    sitemap_urls=$(curl -s "$sitemap_url" | grep -oP '(?<=<loc>)[^<]+')
    for sitemap in $sitemap_urls; do
        urls=$(curl -s "$sitemap" | grep -oP '(?<=<loc>)[^<]+')
        for url in $urls; do
            curl -IL "$url"
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: if I do this sitemap_url="https://*.vgopromo.com/wp-sitemap.xml" will it do it for the subdomains as well ?

Comment: No. I think thats not a good idea. Also then it was not easy like this to receive all available subdomains from your domain. Its better to add a variable, where you can enter all available subdomains. Ill edited with examples.

Comment: # 0 8 * * * /bin/bash /root/warmup.sh   <- every 24 hours correct?

Comment: I dont think you clean your cache every 24 hours? I think best would be to start only when cache was cleaned. Maybe a cron once per week is enough. But thats up on you :)

Comment: no I didnt clean it what is the command to clean the cache ?

Comment: I just asked how often you do it. You wanted this script to warmup your cache. So it does not need to run when you wont clean your cache inside your wordpress. For sure if you want and have enough system ressources do that like you said every 24 hours :)

Comment: how to purge the cache ?

Comment: is there a way to reverse all this curls ?